# How to execute Hydra script for multiple login layers

Tags: php, bash, hydra

I'm trying to test some basic brute force strategy on a locally hosted website by using Hydra. The website has 2 login layers: the first one is a `http-get Basic Auth` and after you login with the Basic Authentication you land on the actual login page that uses `http-post-form`. I already have the password for the Basic Auth layer, and I want to test a list of usernames and passwords on the actual login layer.

For the Basic Auth layer I can use

```
hydra -l username -p password -s 9000 -V 127.0.0.1 http-get "/index.php"
```

which of course is successful since I know the username and password. Now I want to execute another Hydra attack on the second login layer that comes after passing the HTTP Basic Auth.

I tried this command:

```
hydra -l username -p password -s 9000 -V 127.0.0.1 http-get "/index.php" ; hydra -L usernames.txt -P passwords.txt -s 9000 -V 127.0.0.1 http-post-form "/index.php:username=^USER^&password=^PASS^&Login=submit:Login failed - incorrect username or password"
```

This command doesn't work, since `command 1 ; command 2` runs both scripts consecutively but doesn't remember the output of the first command.

Which command can I use to run both commands, but `command 2` should only run after the HTTP Basic Auth is bypassed with `command 1`